# How the property of modulus (A*B)%m = (A%m * B%m) %m is used to find the mod of very large numbers

Tags: algorithm, math, numbers, number-theory, modulo

I saw the property of mod where

`(A*B)%m = (A%m * B%m) %m`

And this property is used in the below algorithm to find the mod of very large numbers.

1. Get one variable to store the answer initialized to zero.
2. Scan the string from left to right,
3. every time multiply the answer by 10 and add the next number and take the modulo and store this as the new answer.

But I'm unable to understand this algorithm . How the property is connected to the algorithm here?

It will be helpful if used an example to understand the underneath math behind the algorithm , for example `12345%100`

Comment: In addition to the property that you cited, the algorithm is using the fact that `12345 = (((1*10 + 2)*10 + 3)*10 +4)*10 + 5`.

Comment: Can you explain in detail?

Comment: `12345 = 10000 + 2000 + 300 + 40 + 5 = 1 * 10000 + 2 * 1000 + 3 * 100 + 4 * 10 + 5 = (((1*10 + 2)*10 + 3)*10 +4)*10 + 5`. Then they repeatedly use the formula `(a * 10 + b) % m = ((a % m) * (10 % m) + (b % m)) % m`.

Comment: This is something that children typically see in primary school, when they learn that a number is even iff its last digit is one of 0,2,4,6,8, and that a number is divisible by 3 iff the sum of its digit is divisible by 3, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Using this algorithm, `23 % k` is computed as

```
(2%k * 10 + 3)%k
((2%k * 10)%k + 3)%k        // because (a+b)%k = (a%k + b)%k  (1)
(((2%k)%k * 10%k)%k + 3)%k  // because (a*b)%k = (a%k * b%k)%k  (2)
((2%k * 10%k)%k + 3)%k      // because (a%k)%k = a%k  (trivial)
((2 * 10)%k + 3)%k          // because (a%k * b%k)%k = (a*b)%k  (2)
(2 * 10 + 3)%k              // because (a%k + b)%k = (a+b)%k  (1)
23%k
```

In other words, `(a%k * p + b)%k = (a * p + b)%k` thanks to that property (2). `b` is the last digit of a number in base `p` (`p = 10` in your example), and `a` is the rest of the number (all the digits but the last).

In my example, `a` is just `2`, but if you apply this recursively, you have your algorithm. The point is that `a * p + b` might be too big to handle, but `a%k * p + b` probably isn't.

Comment: How did you write 23%k as (2%k * 10 + 3)%k in the first line ? And (a+b)%k = (a%k + b)%k is a property of modular arithmetic

Comment: @aravindks That's literally what the algorithm does. Take the first digit, take the modulo, multiply by 10, add the second digit, take the modulo, and so on.